# <h2> is not viewed when i click on the menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Its a onPage site and the problem is, that when i click on a menu-item, the page scroll down, but the  tag is behind the navbar.

You can copy the following code, its my hole basic-page.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/kLy67rdu/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Wiredeiki App </title>
<meta name="description" content="Wiredwiki App">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<style>
body{
    padding-top: 40px;
}
</style>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">

<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Wiredwiki</a>
        </div><!-- Navbar Header-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn navbar-right">Download Now</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a> 
                <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a> 
                <li><a href="#features">Features</a> 
                <li><a href="#faq">Faq</a> 
                <li><a href="#contact">ContactUs</a> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Container-->
</nav><!-- End navbar -->

<!-- jumbotron-->

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Wiredwiki App</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse consectetur </p>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Download App</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Visit store</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Spread the word</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End container -->
</div><!-- End jumbotron-->

<!-- Feedback-->
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="feedback">
            <h2>Feedback.<small> Check out the Awesome Feedback</small></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida quam ac ante rutrum, in mollis ligula mattis. Integer nulla nisi, ullamcorper et posuere vel</p>
                    <footer>John doe</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida quam ac ante rutrum, in mollis ligula mattis. Integer nulla nisi, ullamcorper et posuere vel</p>
                    <footer>John doe</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida quam ac ante rutrum, in mollis ligula mattis. Integer nulla nisi, ullamcorper et posuere vel</p>
                    <footer>John doe</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End row -->
    </section>
</div><!--End Container-->

<!-- call to action -->
<section>
    <div class="well">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h3>Subscribe for more free stuff</h3>
            <p>Enter your name and email</p>

            <form action="" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subscription">Subscribe</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
                <hr>
            </form>


        </div><!-- end Container-->

    </div><!-- end well-->
</section><!-- Call to action -->

<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="gallery">
            <h2>Gallery.<small> Check out the Awesome Gallery</small></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="highway.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Highway heading</h3>
                        <p>This is the caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="river.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>River heading</h3>
                        <p>This is the caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="street.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Street heading</h3>
                        <p>This is the caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="painting.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Painting heading</h3>
                        <p>This is the caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div><!-- End Carousel inner -->
            <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div><!-- End Carousel -->

    </section>
</div>

<!-- features -->
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header" id="features">
            <h2>Features.<small> Some of the coolest Features of this app.</small></h2>
        </div><!-- End Page Header -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa. Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="imac.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div><!-- End row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa. Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="smartphone.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa. Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="user.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                        <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus. Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in euismod dui</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                        <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus. Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in euismod dui</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
                        <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                        <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus. Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in euismod dui</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end row -->

    </section>
</div><!-- End Container -->

<!-- Faq -->

<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="page-header" id="faq">
      <h2>FAQ.<small> Engaging with consumers.</small></h2>
    </div><!-- End Page Header -->

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">
            <a href="#collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
              Question one?
            </a>
          </div><!-- End panel title -->
          <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla. Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Panel collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">
            <a href="#collapse-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
              Question Two?
            </a>
          </div><!-- End panel title -->
          <div id="collapse-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla. Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Panel collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">
            <a href="#collapse-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
              Question Three?
            </a>
          </div><!-- End panel title -->
          <div id="collapse-3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla. Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Panel collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End panel group -->

  </section>
</div><!-- End container -->


<!-- Contact -->

<div class="container">
<section>
  <div class="page-header" id="contact">
      <h2>Contact Us.<small> Contact us for more.</small></h2>
    </div><!-- End Page Header -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <p>Send us a message, or contact us from the address below</p>


        <address>
          <strong>Wiredwiki Pvt Ltd.</strong></br>
          111, Malviya nagar </br>
          Plot no. 45</br>
          New delhi - 110017</br>
          P: +91 9999999999
        </address>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name" placeholder="Enter you name">
            </div>
          </div><!-- End form group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-email" placeholder="Enter you Email Address">
            </div>
          </div><!-- End form group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-url" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Your Website</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-email" placeholder="If you have Any.">
            </div>
          </div><!-- End form group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Any Message</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" 
              cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End form group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>



        </form>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End the row -->

</section>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->

<footer>
  <hr>
    <div class="container text-center">
    <h3>Subscribe for more free stuff</h3>
    <p>Enter your name and email</p>

    <form action="" class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subscription">Subscribe</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>

    </form>

    <hr>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/wiredwiki">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/askorama">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/wiredwiki">YouTube</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>&copy; Copyright @ 2014</p>

  </div><!-- end Container-->


</footer>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: i have put it in a fiddle, see the edit below

Comment: okay are you trying to close the menu?

Comment: I view this on fullscreen on the computer and the <h2> is behind the navbar, only the content after the page-header is visible

Comment: can you little bit provide a scenerio, could not understand the question, what is the <h2> ? just give example from tha page content such as when I click gallery button like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not linking the images to the containers, you should have had the containers have an id and reference that instead!
Your code should be like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Wiredeiki App </title>
<meta name="description" content="Wiredwiki App">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>

<style>
body{
    padding-top: 40px;
}
</style>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#my-navbar">

<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Wiredwiki</a>
        </div><!-- Navbar Header-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn navbar-right">Download Now</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a> 
                <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a> 
                <li><a href="#features">Features</a> 
                <li><a href="#faq">Faq</a> 
                <li><a href="#contact">ContactUs</a> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Container-->
</nav><!-- End navbar -->

<!-- jumbotron-->

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Wiredwiki App</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse consectetur </p>

        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Download App</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Visit store</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Spread the word</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End container -->
</div><!-- End jumbotron-->

<!-- Feedback-->
<div class="container" id="feedback">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header" >
            <h2>Feedback.<small> Check out the Awesome Feedback</small></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida quam ac ante rutrum, in mollis ligula mattis. Integer nulla nisi, ullamcorper et posuere vel</p>
                    <footer>John doe</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida quam ac ante rutrum, in mollis ligula mattis. Integer nulla nisi, ullamcorper et posuere vel</p>
                    <footer>John doe</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <blockquote>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi gravida quam ac ante rutrum, in mollis ligula mattis. Integer nulla nisi, ullamcorper et posuere vel</p>
                    <footer>John doe</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End row -->
    </section>
</div><!--End Container-->

<!-- call to action -->
<section>
    <div class="well">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h3>Subscribe for more free stuff</h3>
            <p>Enter your name and email</p>

            <form action="" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subscription">Subscribe</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
                <hr>
            </form>


        </div><!-- end Container-->

    </div><!-- end well-->
</section><!-- Call to action -->

<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="container" id="gallery">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header" >
            <h2>Gallery.<small> Check out the Awesome Gallery</small></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel slide" id="screenshot-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#screenshot-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="highway.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Highway heading</h3>
                        <p>This is the caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="river.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>River heading</h3>
                        <p>This is the caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="street.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Street heading</h3>
                        <p>This is the caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="painting.jpg" alt="Text of the image">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3>Painting heading</h3>
                        <p>This is the caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div><!-- End Carousel inner -->
            <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="#screenshot-carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div><!-- End Carousel -->

    </section>
</div>

<!-- features -->
<div class="container" id="features">
    <section>
        <div class="page-header" >
            <h2>Features.<small> Some of the coolest Features of this app.</small></h2>
        </div><!-- End Page Header -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa. Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="imac.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div><!-- End row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa. Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="smartphone.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3>This is the heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mauris tortor, eleifend sit amet fringilla ac, tincidunt id massa. Proin et odio mattis, venenatis lacus vel, faucibus elit</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="user.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                        <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                        <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus. Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in euismod dui</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                        <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                        <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus. Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in euismod dui</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span>
                        <h4>This is the Heading</h4>
                        <p>Nam velit est, tempor vel posuere et, auctor a lectus. Aenean gravida, est accumsan dictum rhoncus, lectus mi suscipit lacus, suscipit accumsan augue tellus vitae dolor. Morbi in euismod dui</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end row -->

    </section>
</div><!-- End Container -->

<!-- Faq -->

<div class="container" id="faq">
  <section>
    <div class="page-header" >
      <h2>FAQ.<small> Engaging with consumers.</small></h2>
    </div><!-- End Page Header -->

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">
            <a href="#collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
              Question one?
            </a>
          </div><!-- End panel title -->
          <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla. Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Panel collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">
            <a href="#collapse-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
              Question Two?
            </a>
          </div><!-- End panel title -->
          <div id="collapse-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla. Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Panel collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="panel-title">
            <a href="#collapse-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
              Question Three?
            </a>
          </div><!-- End panel title -->
          <div id="collapse-3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec egestas non urna in fringilla. Praesent consequat est at feugiat faucibus
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Panel collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End panel group -->

  </section>
</div><!-- End container -->


<!-- Contact -->

<div class="container" id="contact">
<section>
  <div class="page-header" >
      <h2>Contact Us.<small> Contact us for more.</small></h2>
    </div><!-- End Page Header -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <p>Send us a message, or contact us from the address below</p>


        <address>
          <strong>Wiredwiki Pvt Ltd.</strong></br>
          111, Malviya nagar </br>
          Plot no. 45</br>
          New delhi - 110017</br>
          P: +91 9999999999
        </address>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <form action="" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name" placeholder="Enter you name">
            </div>
          </div><!-- End form group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-email" placeholder="Enter you Email Address">
            </div>
          </div><!-- End form group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-url" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Your Website</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-email" placeholder="If you have Any.">
            </div>
          </div><!-- End form group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Any Message</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <textarea name="user-message" id="user-message" class="form-control" 
              cols="20" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Message"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End form group -->

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>



        </form>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End the row -->

</section>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->

<footer>
  <hr>
    <div class="container text-center">
    <h3>Subscribe for more free stuff</h3>
    <p>Enter your name and email</p>

    <form action="" class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subscription">Subscribe</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subscription" placeholder="Your name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>

    </form>

    <hr>
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/wiredwiki">Twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/askorama">Facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/wiredwiki">YouTube</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>&copy; Copyright @ 2014</p>

  </div><!-- end Container-->


</footer>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Also, you should use a CSS property for each container, to add a little padding on top